# Export JSON data from MySQL table to CSV

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, export-to-csv, mysql-5.7

I used the following command to export some fields of **MySQL** table including a **JSON** field(*attributes*) into **CSV** file:

```
SELECT name, attributes, product_url FROM products INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/toys.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

But, I get each key-value pair of attributes(JSON field) in separate columns.

***How to get all those key-values(attributes column of MySQL table) in a single column of CSV file?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that was enough to get my job done. I exported those fields into TSV instead of CSV using following slightly modified command:

```
SELECT name, attributes, product_url FROM products INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/toys.tsv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Still, if anyone has an exact solution to the problem, that would be greatly appreciated.